# Is there a way to check if a post has been sent to Twitter?

Tags: discussion, twitter

One way to check if a question has been tweeted is via the edit history ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/7238/revisions)), so I'm curious if there's another way. For example, what about a question that hasn't been edited?

Comment: I guess the mention in the revision history is new then? Or does it only apply to sites with their own Twitter account? ([This history](http://superuser.com/posts/243669/revisions) does not show [this February 10th tweet](http://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/35526526615158784).)

Comment: Did this show as a revision in your recent activity?

Comment: @arj No, it didn't show, either in my inbox or in 'recent activity'.

Comment: @arj UL appears on the blog post, and SU doesn't, so many there's some difference in the setup.

Answer (score 4):

This [event is now recorded in the PostHistory table in SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) but its earliest record is August 10th, 2011.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/732487) shows the records with a posthistorytypeid = 25:

```sql
select postid as [Post Link]
     , creationdate
from posthistory 
where posthistorytypeid = 25  -- Post Tweeted
order by creationdate desc
```

Due to the weekly update of SEDE, on Monday morning, you might have to wait a bit before the data is available.

As an alternative you can look at the [timeline](https://superuser.com/posts/256459/timeline#history_5de94ea5-eb54-4898-9c1b-afa1c56e0108) of a question. There are [handy scripts](https://stackapps.com/search?q=timeline+%5Bscript%5D+is%3Aq) that add a link to  each post for easy access. Otherwise these link is quickly constructed by doing `\posts\{postid}\timeline` in the addressbar of your browser.